# allowing for missing parent in jsoup selector

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I want to retrieve books from a website but that website uses different html to show the same thing. In some pages it has a `div` followed by an `ul` and then the `li`, like this:

```
<div class="book-description">
   <ul>
      <li>info 1</li>
      <li>info 2</li>
      <li>info 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

To iterate over the `li` I would simply do: `doc.select("div.book-description > ul > li")`

On others it goes directly from `div` to `li`, like this:

```
<div class="book-description">
   <li>info 1</li>
   <li>info 2</li>
   <li>info 3</li>
</div>
```

The previous syntax would not work with this page, I would need to use `doc.select("div.book-description > li")`
Is there a syntax I can use to specify that the `ul` may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `doc.select("div.book-description li")` ?

If your list have no nested lists, this selector would be ok.